# C# Restsharp - How to verify the content result is unexpected result

Tags: c#, restsharp

Code to get the content result

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = (string)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
```

The `response.content` should return ether one of this 4 msg.

- OK
- INVALID_MESSAGE_ID
- MESSAGE_NOT_FOUND
- INTERNAL_ERROR

What if the API returning something else, how can I verify that?

Comment: the API response will return an http code (assuming it is an http based service) based on the code you can find out the status

Comment: What about a `if` or `switch` with a `default`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the content:

```
if(content != "OK" && content != "INVALID_MESSAGE_ID" && content != "MESSAGE_NOT_FOUND" && content != "INTERNAL_ERROR") {
    //Do some handling, like logging
}
```

Or:

```
switch(content) {
    case "OK":
        // Do something, when content is OK
        break;
    case "INVALID_MESSAGE_ID":
        // Do something, when content is INVALID_MESSAGE_ID
        break;
    case "MESSAGE_NOT_FOUND":
        // Do something, when content is MESSAGE_NOT_FOUND
        break;
    case "INTERNAL_ERROR":
        // Do something, when content is INTERNAL_ERROR
        break;
    case default:
        // Do something, if no case is matched
        break;
}
```

Comment: very useful. thanks for help! i got the idea now... :)